# MATLAB Out of Memory Error

Tags: matlab, memory

Relevant code:

```
Hf = ((j*2*pi*f).^2 + Wo.^2)/((j*2*pi*f).^2 + 2*Wo*j*2*pi*f + Wo.^2);
```

It runs out of memory on the Hf = ' ' line. The only non-numerical part of this statement is the f term. Typing in the command window :

> > size(f)
> >
> > ans = 65536 1

I'm not used to MATLAB at all, but I don't think this is something I can fix by freeing up memory before I make that statement.

Here's the memory after getting the error:

> > Maximum possible array:     10096 MB (1.059e+10 bytes) *
> >
> > Memory available for all arrays:     10096 MB (1.059e+10 bytes) *
> >
> > Memory used by MATLAB:      3716 MB (3.896e+09 bytes)
> >     Physical Memory (RAM):      8173 MB (8.570e+09 bytes)
> >
> > - Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.

Here it is before (after I hit >>clear all)

> > Maximum possible array:     10095 MB (1.059e+10 bytes) *
> >
> > Memory available for all arrays:     10095 MB (1.059e+10 bytes) *
> >
> > Memory used by MATLAB:      3693 MB (3.872e+09 bytes)
> >
> > Physical Memory (RAM):      8173 MB (8.570e+09 bytes)
> >
> > - Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.

I tried restarting MATLAB -- No luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part before `/` is a column vector (of 65536) elements, as well as the part after that. I guess you wanted to do elementwise division - in such a case, use `./` .

This way, the backslash operator, "dividing" given vectors, creates a matrix with 65536*65536 elements, so it is not surprising that there is a problem with memory.

Comment: That was it! I knew it would be super simple. MATLAB is weird to me, after doing so much C/C++ programming and everything.